# Best practice for different <templates> requiring the same <script> tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am a bit confused about how would be the Vue way to approach this situation.

Currently I have two search inputs that have very different templates (one at the navbar and other at the page level) rendering. If I choose to create two different components (what seems to be the easier and more common approach), I would have two components with identical `<script>` logic.

Is this something desired and compatible with the SFC standards or is there a more DRY compatible approach that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using Vue2, you can use [Vue Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).
if you are using Vue3, you can use and export function from  [Composite API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html)